# Does the design of Orlan's entry hatch preclude the use of waist bearings?

Tags: spacesuits

One major difference between the [Extravehicular Mobility Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extravehicular_Mobility_Unit) and the [Orlan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlan_space_suit) space suits is the entry method. EMU uses waist entry while Orlan uses rear entry. The waist entry allows EMU to use a waist bearing between the Hard Upper Torso and the soft Lower Torso Assembly. On the other hand, Orlan has a rear entry hatch that extends around the hip of the astronauts.

Jordan ([2006](http://doi.org/1721.1/35296), p. 55) reports that EMU has more joint bearings and lower operating pressure than Orlan-M; as a consequence EMU is more mobile than Orlan-M.

While the rear-entry i-Suit has a waist bearing ([Graziosi et al. 2006](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/lunar/constellation/GraziosiEtAl_SAE-TP-2006-01-2143_DRATSEvaluationOfRearEntryI-Suit.pdf)), its hatch is located much higher than Orlan's.

Therefore, does the design of Orlan's entry hatch preclude the use of waist bearings?

Comment: Not all readers will know all space jargon (I certainly don't!) This [ORLAN](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ORLAN_par_Claude_Truong-Ngoc_2013.jpg) could be from space as well! I hope you don't mind that I've added some links.

Comment: yes it does....